# Unexpected \W? behavior with regex lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, backtracking

In a simple regex I want to match segments where "1 is not followed by 'a', possibly preceded by whitespaces", '1' may be followed by a nonword character (such as ",").

`1\W(?!\s*a)` functions correctly (on test strings "1 a" and "1, a") and
`1\W?(?!\s*a)` does not function correctly. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: What I do not understand is why
1(?!(\W*)a)
functions correctly, but
1(\W*)(?!a)
does not

Answer (score 1):

The `1\W?(?!\s*a)` pattern matches `1, a` like this:

- `1` in the pattern matches `1` in the string
- `\W?` matches the comma
- `(?!\s*a)` sees the space and `a` and fails this *path*, ***backtracks*** to the position before `,`
- `\W?` now matches the empty space before `,`
- `(?!\s*a)` no longer sees the space and `a` (as there is a `,` and space) and returns success status. You get a match.

See the [regex debugger in action](https://regex101.com/r/DEvqKY/2/debugger):

[image]

The solutions is to use a possessive quantifier or an atomic group (they behave the same way):

```
1\W?+(?!\s*a)
   ^^
(?>1\W?)(?!\s*a)
^^^^   ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DEvqKY/3)

**If your regex engine does not support atomic groups or possessive quantifiers** move the lookahead to the left to the position right after the first (from the right) obligatory pattern (here, it is `1`) and include the optional subpattern(s) into the lookahead pattern at the start:

```
1(?!\W?\s*a)\W?
 ^^^^^^     ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DEvqKY/4).

Answer (score 0):

The atomic grouping was missing.
1(?>\W*)(?!a)